# How to expand and collapse rows based on a row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your assistant in expanding and collapsing a number of rows based on a row using javascript. The row are generated dynamically based on the returned values from the query. I need to display the folders' names and below it the sub folders' names. Here is the code for the table:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="106">
<%

  int i=1;
  int j=0

  do
  {
 //SQL Query

  String sz_FolderName=res.getString(2);    

  String sz_NumberOfDocument=RS_NumberOfDocument.getString(1);

%>

    <tr>
      <td><%=i%></td>
      <td>
        <span style="text-decoration: none">
            <%=sz_FolderName%><img id="image<%=i%>" src="../expand.gif"> </span></td>

      <td>
        <p align="center"><%=sz_NumberOfDocument%></td>

    </tr>

<%   
 //SQL Query

            String Subsz_FolderNumber=Subres.getString(1);  
            String Subsz_FolderName=Subres.getString(2);    

%>  
    <tr>
        <td>
                <p style="text-align: left">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                <p style="text-align: left">&nbsp; 
                &#9658; <%=Subsz_FolderName%></td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                <%=sz_FolderName%></td>
    </tr>

 <%
        }

j++;
i++;
} 

%>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? And please for those kinda questions -related to html or js- post the html output not the php/asp source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can show your element via js like following:

```
element.style.display = 'none';           // Hide
element.style.display = 'block';          // Show
element.style.display = 'inline';         // Show
element.style.display = 'inline-block';   // Show
```

Select elements by id/name/class/etc. and change their display status.